# mysql query to return users who are following me is returning this error: Undefined property: stdClass::$user_id

Tags: php, mysql

This code is for my follower system. I want to query the database to show the users who are following me. the function show_users_following_you(my id) is returning an error on line 9. can someone explain where it is coming from?

This code is for my follower system. I want to query the database to show the users who are following me. the function show_users_following_you(my id) is returning an error. can someone explain where it is coming from?

```
function show_users_following_you($user_id=0){

    if ($user_id > 0){

        $follow = array();

        $fsql = "select follower_id from following where user_id='". $user_id ."'";
        $fresult = mysql_query($fsql);

        while($f = mysql_fetch_object($fresult)){
            array_push($follow, $f->user_id);
        }

        if (count($follow)){
            $id_string = implode(',', $follow);
            $extra =  " and id in ($id_string)";
        }else{
            return array();
        }
    }

    $users = array();
    $sql = "select id, username from users where status='active' $extra order by username";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){

        $users[$data->id] = $data->username;

    }

    return $users;

}
```

**Comments Table structure is**

Two columns:

User_id corresponds to who is being followed and Follower_id corresponds to who is doing the following.

Comment: What line indicates the error?

Comment: the error is on line 9 Undefined property: stdClass::$user_id

Comment: Attention to case-sensitive when calling an object's properties. Is not the same $f->user_id to $f->User_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fsql = "select follower_id from following
    where user_id='$user_id'";
$fresult = mysql_query($fsql);

while($f = mysql_fetch_object($fresult)){
     array_push($follow, $f->user_id);
}
```

Your fetched object has the property `follower_id`, but you're trying to read `user_id`.

(Also, make sure to escape dynamic values (in this case, `$user_id`) using `mysql_real_escape_string` or PDO. As it stands, this is potentially open to SQL injection.)

Comment: If you have a dynamic value that is expected to be an integer it is better to use intval() as opposed to mysql_real_escape_string. It is also a good idea not to quote integer values in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[...]
while($f = mysql_fetch_object($fresult)){
   array_push($follow, $f->user_id);
}
```

Try

```
[...]
while($f = mysql_fetch_object($fresult)){
   array_push($follow, $f->User_id);
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the query

"select follower_id from following where user_id='$user_id'"

To

"select user_id from following where user_id='". $user_id ."'"

Comment: What makes you think this would be an improvement?